# SVG mouseover and hover bug in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, svg, hover, mouseover

```
.dot {
  stroke:none;
  fill: red;
}

.dot:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" width="100%"  height="100%" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
<g transform="translate(0,0) scale(1)">
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="0.5" transform="scale(1)" class="dot"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Check out this https://jsfiddle.net/c1j1q7hj/10/

In Firefox the hover doesn't fire on the circle, in Chrome it does

When radius on the circle is less than 1, hover is not correctly triggered (nor mouseover events). Setting the radius to 1 and adjusting the transform on the circle doesn't work

Is this a bug in Firefox ?

Comment: The circle is filled in yellow for me in Firefox? If you mean hovering on the border, than no, it's not working for me in FF.. I don't know if that's a bug in Firefox

Comment: It works for me in FF 51.0.1 for Mac.